# Arguments in url break other view on same page

Tags: views

Whenever I go to a url that has parameters in for example www.sitename.com?page=1

It breaks another view that uses contextual filter and looks like this

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out. If you have a view page with a pager and another view block with a pager on the same page, they conflict.